# Changing SATA/SAS and SSD/HDD mix capabilities on a raid controller

Tags: hardware-raid, sas, sata, lsi, storcli

We are currently facing the challenge of replacing disks in a raid 1 configuration of a standalone server. The server is quiet old and uses 10k SAS HDD drives together with a Fujitsu D2616 (based on LSI SAS2108). One of the two drives failed. Instead of buying expensive (and compared to SSDs quiet slow) SAS disks, we decided to use SATA SSD drives instead.
While replacing the failed disk with the newly inserted SSD, we received an error about not appropriate attributes:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/c0/e252/s4 Failure    38 physical disk does not have appropriate attributes
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The command we used to replace the disk was:
`storcli64.exe /c0/e252/s4 insert dg=0 array=0 row=1`

After digging a bit what the issue could be, we found the following under the capabilities section in the output from `storcli64.exe /c0 show all`

```
Mix in Enclosure = Allowed
Mix of SAS/SATA of HDD type in VD = Not Allowed
Mix of SAS/SATA of SSD type in VD = Not Allowed
Mix of SSD/HDD in VD = Not Allowed
```

Which would explain the error received earlier. Since the old disks are SAS HDD and the new ones are SATA SSD.

In [this post](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/should-be-sticky-samsung-840-and-840-pro-are-not-lsi-megaraid-compatible.1653/#post-13779) I found a vague description of changing several capabilities section using a tool called megascu. Sadly I could not find further description nor a download link for megascu. And also I was not able to find a way to change this capabilities with storcli.

Is it possible to change the mix of SAS/SATA and SSD/HDD capabilities of a raid controller or are this fixed values. And if yes, how can they be changed?

---

Some more information on our setup (from `storcli64.exe /c0 show all`):

```
Version :
=======
Firmware Package Build = 12.9.0-0051
Firmware Version = 2.90.83-1078
Bios Version = 3.18.00_4.09.05.00_0x0416A000
Preboot CLI Version = 04.04-010:#%00008
WebBIOS Version = 6.0-18-e_13-Rel
NVDATA Version = 2.06.03-0014
Boot Block Version = 2.02.00.00-0000
Bootloader Version = 01.250.04.219
Driver Name = megasas.sys
Driver Version = 4.5.1.64

TOPOLOGY :
========
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT       Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID1 Dgrd  N  136.218 GB dsbl N  N   dflt N      N
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID1 Dgrd  N  136.218 GB dsbl N  N   dflt N      N
 0 0   0   252:0    0   DRIVE Onln  N  136.218 GB dsbl N  N   dflt -      N
 0 0   1   -        -   DRIVE Msng  -  136.218 GB -    -  -   -    -      N
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


VD LIST :
=======

---------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC       Size Name
---------------------------------------------------------------
0/0   RAID1 Dgrd  RW     Yes     NRWTD -   OFF 136.218 GB
---------------------------------------------------------------

Cac=CacheCade|Rec=Recovery|OfLn=OffLine|Pdgd=Partially Degraded|Dgrd=Degraded
Optl=Optimal|RO=Read Only|RW=Read Write|HD=Hidden|TRANS=TransportReady|B=Blocked
|
Consist=Consistent|R=Read Ahead Always|NR=No Read Ahead|WB=WriteBack|
AWB=Always WriteBack|WT=WriteThrough|C=Cached IO|D=Direct IO|sCC=Scheduled
Check Consistency

Physical Drives = 2

PD LIST :
=======

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                     Sp
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     0 Onln   0 136.218 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST9146803SS               U
252:4     2 UGood  -  465.25 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB U
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```